# How can I fetch all the newly minted SPL tokens in real-time?

Tags: spl-token, token, spl-token-program, spl-associated-token-account

Can someone confirm whether all recently created SPL tokens originate from the same source protocol/contract, such as TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA?

If not, could you please provide guidance on how to retrieve real-time information on newly minted SPL tokens?

Thank you

Comment: Yes. All the token and mint accounts are owned by the Token program (TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA) and originate via instructions to this program.

Comment: Don't forget token-2022 at `TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb` which does see some usage!

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question, Im also interested! Im leaning down the path of websocket? somehow?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/7521)

Comment: I believe the optimal approach is going the websocket route + getProgramAccounts. But I ended up:

1. First fetching the signatures using `getSignaturesForAddress`

Comment: 2. Fetching transaction with `getTransaction`

then I read the `Instructions` and `InnerInstructions` of these transactions and determined the the trx type by the `type` parameter in there.

Good luck!

If you find a better approach, do add it below <3